# Hardcoded OG (Opengraph) tags on CMS homepage Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cms, cms-pages, page

On magento 1 I had a code snippet that would tell if the currently loaded page was a cms page, or a particular page and I could use that code to implement the OG tags for the homepage.

Facebook doesn’t make a good job of extracting any info from our current homepage, and while all categories and products work properly, the homepage returns nothing when posted to Facebook.

Does anyone know if a similar code to what I explained for mage 1 is available for mage 2 or if there is a template file that is cms page exclusive somewhere where I could hard code the OG tags into?